# Using VBA in Microsoft Access to read a Microsoft Excel workbook and then close it gracefully

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2016

I almost have this working.  However, what I'm finding is that Microsoft Excel remains open in the background (as visible in Task Manager) even after my VBA procedure is completed.  If I run the procedure a second time it'll error out on me.  If I kill the Microsoft Excel process then I can run my VBA procedure again without errors.

I've included a reference to the Microsoft Excel 16.0 object library.

Here's the code I have:

```
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim myWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strWorksheetName As String

'Open the file as read-only.
strFilePath = <Path to file>
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath, , True)
appExcel.Visible = False

Set myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Sheets(<The name of the worksheet I'm interested in>)

<read stuff from the worksheet in the same fashion that I would if I were doing this in Excel itself>

'Close the workbook without saving any changes.
myWorkbook.Close False
'appExcel.Quit
'Set appExcel = Nothing
```

It doesn't seem to matter if I uncomment the "appExcel.Quit" or "set appExcel = Nothing" statements.  So what's the graceful way to properly close the workbook so that it gets completely removed from memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To get rid from the issue, you need to use these line.*

- Close workbook, without saving & quit from Excel:

  ```
   xlWB.Close True
   Set xlWB = Nothing
   XLapp.Quit
   Set XLapp = Nothing
  ```

---

- Close, save workbook & quit from Excel:

  ```
  xlApp.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   xlWB.Save
   xlWB.Close True
   xlapp.Quit
   Set xlapp = Nothing
  ```

Comment: I believe in the example to close without saving the line should be, "xlWB.Close False"

Comment: @dutsnekcirf,, since xlWB.Save is not used then it works,, properly. Or you may use xlWB.Close savechanges:=True/False.

Comment: @dutsnekcirf ,, glad to help U,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

As you are closing the workbook with `myWorkBook.Close False`, then you are closing workbook as well as excel, so the last two lines to `appExcel.Quit` and destroy COM Object does not execute.